# How can I use a font icon as a background image?

Tags: css, svg, fonts, icons

1) I know I can use a font icon using , pseudo selectors (before, after) and "content", but it is not a scalable solution, because I need to make many changes to padding, left, top etc in different situations

2) Using Data URI an svg is ok, but I need to change the fill/color of the svg
based on different actions. I tried the fill property but it is not really working.

I can change/edit the color external but I have a lot of variations and again doesn't scale

---

The icon fonts(ex: FontAwesome) come with SVG files for the browsers. It is possible to use somehow that file in css (like image sprites) ?

Comment: Pseudo element trick is super flexible. I don't really understand why you can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify properties of SVG's it will have to be placed inline. So using an SVG as a background **and** modifying properties won't work.

Libraries like FontAwesome give you a `font`, not `svg`'s which you can't set as a background either.

I don't see the problem of using the *psuedo-selectors* :before and :after for this. They are very scalable in my opinion.

If you really want to do it differently you should share some of your code with us so we can get a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to position the icons inside form fields, left or right. I have many variations as size of the input but also as state(defines where left or wright) and when. Because <input> can't have before,after I need to add a parent element and the icon element. Combine this with many variations for css(padding,margins etc) I have a lot of work. Using them as a background(add or remove a class) with just the input element I think is less "intensive", less code and more scalable.

Comment: What you could do is create a input group div, which contains an input element and a div with the background. Then select the background element .input-group .background-element and position it absolute into the input. Or select it with input + .background-element

Comment: @user3541631 let me know if it worked. If you're struggling with something feel free to share the code you made and i'll take a look at it :)